# Can we add COUNT as a column in the result set?

Tags: postgresql

I have big query which has distinct data of results .

I wonder if its possible to add a COUNT column which calculates the total results count and display as a column .

Say I have results below from my big query

```html
col_12_0_|ppi_event_id|col_1_0|col_11_0_|col_13_0_|col_14_0_|col_15_0_|col_17_0| 
---------|------------|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|--------| 
    27981|        3249| 149056|IN       |ongoing  |true     |Asia     |       0| 
    27989|        3249| 149060|FUR      |ongoing  |false    |Asia     |       1|
```

Expected results as below. Added count column in end with total records .

If I have 10000 records in total then count display 10000 in front of each column .

```html
col_12_0_|ppi_event_id|col_1_0|col_13_0_|col_14_0_|col_15_0_|col_17_0_|Count    |
---------|------------|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|--------|
    27981|        3249| 149056|ongoing  |true     |Asia     |       0 |2       |
    27989|        3249| 149060|ongoing  |false    |Asia     |        1|2       |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `count(*) over ()` as the expression. A small example:

```
testdb=# with fake_data as (
select 'foo' as col1, 'bar' as col2 union all
select 'foo', 'baz')
select *, count(*) over () AS total_rows_returned from fake_data;
 col1 | col2 | total_rows_returned 
------+------+---------------------
 foo  | bar  |                   2
 foo  | baz  |                   2
(2 rows)
```